# Orchard CMS - Multi-Lingual and multi-culture

Tags: orchardcms

How to work with Multi-Lingual and multi-culture. For example if we publishing some content from, US in US English (en_US) and French - Canada(fr-ca) languages and it should be publish as per the respective country time zone.Is any built-in culture module having this same or similar functionality available with CMS ? If it is possible then how can we implement or need to develop custom functionality for the same.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a built-in module to make contents localizable. Just go to the modules screen and search for content localization. You can then add the localization part to any content type, and translate. The documentation can be found here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Creating-global-ready-applications/